# E-commerce which file type to use to format orders

Tags: php, codeigniter, e-commerce, file-type, orders

I'm wondering which is the best practice to format into a file the received orders?

For now i'm using PDF but i would like to know if is out of there a lighter and more usefull file type.

thanks

Comment: @Yada  uhm ... i mean plain text is not so good when reading not!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do with those files...

- If it's just some kind of report and you want to *print*, *eMail* or just *archive* it and keep the design, **PDF** seems the right choice
- If you just need the pure data and want to *run calculations*, *collect statistics*, etc. and you need to keep it flexible in terms of changes/additions, you should export into something like **XLS** (Excel)
- If you just need to *display* the data *on demand* or you just want to *aggregate some key data* for a *quick overview*, you can just keep it in the database and just call a **php-script** on demand
- If you need all of this, maybe it would be a good idea to just save the data as **CSV** and then process it for whatever purpose in any application.

I hope this answers your question in some way.